# How can I Read my Logcat programmatically line by line

Tags: android, logcat

I want to read my Log cat using my app itself line by line. Here is the code i placed it below

```
  try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -v time");//logcat -v time//logcat -d
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
          log.append(line);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        System.out.println("logas = "+log);
        tv.setText(log.toString());

      } catch (IOException e) {
      }
```

So basically i want to adjust this code to read log cat until use stops it. So i should start working with asyncTask or there is other solution ?

Comment: Bear in mind that, as of Android 4.1, that this will only show messages logged by your process.

Comment: You can still read the logcat in 4.1+ if you use for root permissions